# How to upload songs from Ubuntu 10.4 to iPhone 3?

Tags: iphone, ubuntu-10.04, music, upload

How do I add songs to my iPhone from my Ubuntu 10.4 OS?

I see the iPhone is recognized by Rhythmbox, but I can't do anything with it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick tutorial on how to use any portable device (Cell phones, PDA... ) with Ubuntu.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PortableDevices/iPhone

> **Syncing with Rhythmbox**
>
> After connecting the iPod, open Rhythmbox and click on your iPod name under Devices on the left panel.
>
> You can play music from the iPod and transfer music to it by drag-and-dropping files from the Library onto the iPod icon. Please note: you might need to restart the Rythmbox for it to recognize the album art on the newly uploaded tracks.

Comment: Followed the steps, nothing happens. I can't add songs to the IPHONE from my Ubuntu machine :-(

Answer (score 0):

You can also install GTKPOD. In some cases it works better, but Rhytmbox has more organizing features.

[Manual](http://ionz.org/2009/getting-amarok-or-gtkpod-to-work-with-iphone-3g-or-itouch-2g/)

Comment: Followed the steps, nothing happens. I can't add songs to the IPHONE from my Ubuntu machine :-(

Comment: What iOS do you have?

Comment: The phone is 3.  The version under about is 3.1.3 (7E18)

Comment: I have device with 3.1.2 and it works in Rhytmbox and GTKPOD.

Answer (score 0):

I've heard [Songbird](http://www.getsongbird.com/) has some [add-ons](http://www.readwriteweb.com/start/2009/06/songbird-releases-iphone-sync.php) which lets you sync with iPhone. I like the player itself, and used to use it for my iPod classic. Never tried it with the iPhone though.